# Angular 8 Leaflet put marker onclick

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular8

I try to put a marker when I click over the map

I use this method

```
  private selectLocation () {

this.map.on('click', function(e) {
  var coord = e.latlng;
  var lat = coord.lat;
  var lng = coord.lng;
  console.log('You clicked the map at latitude: ' + lat + ' and longitude: ' + lng);

  var mp = new L.Marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(this.map);
    //alert(mp.getLatLng());
 });
}
```

I call this on ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initMap();
  this.selectLocation();
}
```

But after the map appear and I click over, the console show this error

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
>           at NewClass.addTo (leaflet-src.js:6559)
>           at NewClass. (georreferencia.component.ts:59)
>           at NewClass.fire (leaflet-src.js:593)
>           at NewClass._fireDOMEvent (leaflet-src.js:4452)
>           at NewClass._handleDOMEvent (leaflet-src.js:4409)
>           at HTMLDivElement.handler (leaflet-src.js:2679)
>           at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
>           at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>           at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)

How could I show a Marker when I click over the map?

Comment: Could you reproduce it with stackblitz?

Comment: I create https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyjfz9 but I don't know why the page don't use the leaflet npm (I've installed at dependencies, but the browser show me Can't find package:leaflet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an anonymous function and in it's scope the `this` keyword doesn't reference to the leaflet `map` instance. You can avoid this by using an arrow function instead of the classic ES5 anonymous function beacause there are no binding of `this` in arrow functions.

```
private selectLocation() {

    this.map.on('click', (e) => {
        var coord = e.latlng;
        var lat = coord.lat;
        var lng = coord.lng;
        console.log('You clicked the map at latitude: ' + lat + ' and longitude: ' + lng);

        var mp = new L.Marker([lat, lng]).addTo(this.map);
        alert(mp.getLatLng());
    });
}
```